# Capture part of text from image and highlight captured text

Tags: android, ocr

I am new to android. My challenge is to create an application which captures part of text from image and highlight captured text.

Ex:

Right now getting below result by using [sample](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr)

[image]

But i need result as

[image]

highlight phone number, email and website and need to capture those fields from image. Is it possible to navigate website when user click on highlighted part of website?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the above library
then you will get below function in `CaptureActivity`

```
boolean handleOcrDecode(OcrResult ocrResult) {}
```

in this function you can filter the text that you want from overall text.
After filtering the data show custom dailog with mobile number and email.
And make it email clickable so it will redirect the user to website.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response mr. prashant bhoir i did filtering after result but library highlights complete data but i need to highlight  only phone number, email and website.

Comment: if you having the text then you can apply specific pattern to get spectific data use below pattern to get Email address String s = "*** test@gmail.com&&^ test2@gmail.com((& ";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+").matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            Log.e("EMAILLL",m.group());
        }

Comment: above pattern will give you the email address from string

Comment: I know we can extract data from if we text (as you said above) my problem is not only text gathering. Notice images on my post "highlight only phone number, email and website" this is what i ask.

Comment: in google vision you will get ocr text in below class object. OcrGraphic graphic = mGraphicOverlay.getGraphicAtLocation(rawX, rawY);
TextBlock text = null;
text = graphic.getTextBlock();